# Update query using JPA in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update a column in a table in spring using JPA repository using following query

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE  Price p SET p.price=:price where p.timePeriod=:timePeroid and p.outletVariety.outletProduct.outlet.id=:oId and p.outletVariety.variety.id=:vId")
Integer updatePriceForVarietyandOutlet(@Param("price") Double price,@Param("timePeroid") LocalDate timePeroid,@Param("oId") Long oId , @Param("vId") Long vId);
```

But I am getting following exception

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement

I read somewhere that JOIN is not allowed in JPA update so I tried using native query as follow

```
update pi.price join pi.outlet_product_variety on pi.price.outlet_vareity_id=pi.outlet_product_variety.id join pi.outlet_product on pi.outlet_product_variety.outlet_product_id=pi.outlet_product.id set price =10 where  time_period='2018-01-01' and vid=698
```

But its still not working and no exception is coming.
What is the solution to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: In logs you should have more information, and it should start with Caused by:

Comment: @marok Thanks for sugesstion. Also please tell is native query the right way to go?

Comment: I prefer not to use native queries unless it's easier than none native query

Comment: @marok Okay, but in case of update in which join are needed native is necessary?

Comment: As @marok asked in the first comment. Show the logs and the SQL statement that Hibernate produced.

Comment: It's not necessary. Firstly look at logs for cause.

Comment: Actually what he posted is from the logs. Same problem here using DB2.